# Parsing xml with jquery with conditional for attributes

Tags: jquery, xml, if-statement, conditional-statements

I was tryng to parse this xml:
http://henriquebarone.animatubo.com/spider/jquery/teste.xml

Writing this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "teste.sif",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: Parser 
    });
});

function Parser(sif) {  
    $(sif).find('canvas').each(function(){

        canvas_name = $(this).find('name').text();
        $('<title>'+canvas_name+'</title>').appendTo('head');

        canvas_width = $(this).attr('width');
        canvas_height = $(this).attr('height');
        $('<div id="canvas" style="width:'+canvas_width+'px; height:'+canvas_height+'px; border: solid 1px black; margin: 20px auto"></div>').appendTo('body'); 

        $(this).find('layer').each(function(){
            layer_type = $(this).attr('type');
            if ( layer_type == 'import' ) {
                $(this).find('param').each(function(){
                    param_name = $(this).attr('name');
                    if ( param_name == 'filename' ) {
                        file_name = $(this).find('string').text();
                        $('<div class="import" style="width:50px; height:50px; backgound-img: url('+file_name+')"').appendTo('#canvas');
                    }

                });
            }
        });

    }); 
}
```

For each `<layer>` tag with the attribute `type="import"`, I want to get its child `<param>` with the attribute `name="filename"`, from which I want the text of the `<string>` tag.

Comment: I've rephrased your question to make it easier to follow, but it's possible I've interpreted it wrong, could you check?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(sif).find('layer[type="import"] param[name="filename"] string')
```

should find what you want. I made a [jsFiddle with an example](http://jsfiddle.net/GBAVG/3/).